# Grafana : How to convert Row title on grafana dashboard to lower case by default the row title is in capital letters

Tags: monitoring, grafana

change the row title to lower case or camel case .by default the row title is in Capital letters and there is no option to change it .

Answer (score 0):

The row title in a dashboard is in the same case that you write it. Grafana does not do any conversions. Maybe it used to on older versions, what version of Grafana are you using?

Here is an example of a mixed cased row title in Grafana 4.3.2:

[image]